# fwrite() and special characters

Tags: php

this is the URL to upload in my website the "file.txt" with a "var$" content:

```
http://www.mywebsite.com/fwrite.php?stringData=var$&myFile=file.txt
```

The content of "fwrite.php" is:

```
<?php
$myFile = $_GET['myFile'];
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'w') or die("can't open file");
$stringData = $_GET['stringData'];
fwrite($fh, $stringData);
fclose($fh);
?>
```

It works well, but if the "var$" content contains special characters (like a "+" for example), "file.txt" will have a blank space instead of the correct character.

How could i solve it? Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

try encoding

```
mb_convert_encoding($file, 'HTML-ENTITIES', "UTF-8");
```

Answer (score 1):

**Vulnerability police**

```
$myFile = $_GET['myFile'];
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'w')
```

Hold it right there! This is dangerous code; even if permissions would normally not allow much damage to be done, you should at least sanitize the variable (lest paths such as `../../../etc/passwd` are passed:

```
if (isset($_GET['myFile'])) {
    $fileName = basename($_GET['myFile']); // strip off all paths
    $fh = fopen($fileName, 'w') or die('...');
}
```

**Encoding of `+`**

If a literal `+` occurs in the QS portion of the URL, it will be converted to a space according to standard [RFC behaviour](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc3986.html).

If a value of `hello+world` was intended it must be encoded like:

```
stringData=hello%2Bworld
```

Answer (score 0):

Thak you guys, i've solved using %2B instead the "+" symbol.

Is this correct to fix the vulnerabilty?

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['myFile'])) {
    $myFile = basename($_GET['myFile']);
    $fh = fopen($myFile, 'w') or die("can't open file");
}
$stringData = $_GET['stringData'];
fwrite($fh, $stringData);
fclose($fh);
?>
```